# How can I convert a standard 'select' tag into react-select

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

Im want to turn this  into a  from react-select. All the data being passed through works perfectly with  but when I change it to  it doesn't work (because it requires other options), I was wondering how to make this piece of code compatible with React-Select.

```
<div>
   <select value={this.state.currency} onChange={this.getTest}>
      {this.state.items.map((obj, index) => 
         <option key={${index}-${obj.country}} value={obj}> {obj} </option>
      )} 
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify "value" to your select element.
Rather you need to set your state accordingly on onChange function.

If this was done to somehow "bind" the select option and the state, you're probably not going the react way (probably due to Angular background where such two way bindings is the way to go).

Answer (score 0):

Good example from library

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null,
  }
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}
```